# file readlink functionality

Tags: file, elixir, symlink

Assuming you have a symbolic link: 
**/tmp/zoo2 -> /tmp/zoo**

And you only know **/tmp/zoo2**, how do you resolve the symlink to get to **/tmp/zoo**

In the shell you use **readlink** or in Ruby you do **File.readlink**.

Does Elixir have something similar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `:file.read_link`:

```
iex(1)> :file.read_link "/tmp/zoo2"
{:ok, '/tmp/zoo'}
```

If the link is relative, you can get the absolute target by calling `:filename.absname`, giving the directory of the link as the base directory:

```
iex(1)> link = "/tmp/zoo2"
"/tmp/zoo2"
iex(2)> {:ok, relative_target} = :file.read_link link
{:ok, 'zoo'}
iex(3)> absolute_target = :filename.absname relative_target, :filename.dirname link
"/tmp/zoo"
```